# Errors when making basic Javascript slideshow with navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a javascript slideshow that has a forward and back button. All I need are 8 images that I can click a button and either go to the next picture or previous. However, my code doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I assume it's a simple fix but it's late and I fee like I've tried everything. When I say it doesn't work, I'm referring to that the browser either returns an error saying "unable to parse background-image" (only occurs when I remove if/then statements and only run the else part, without `else` in front of course) or it simply crashes, likely due to an endless loop when I try to run it with the if/then statements. Here is a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/AZchy/. Thanks for your help!

Here is my javascript:

```
var images = new Array(8);
images[0] = "url('screen1.jpg')";
images[1] = "url('screen2.jpg')";
images[2] = "url('screen3.jpg')";
images[3] = "url('screen4.jpg')";
images[4] = "url('screen5.jpg')";
images[5] = "url('screen6.jpg')";
images[6] = "url('screen7.jpg')";
images[7] = "url('screen8.jpg')";
var i = 0;

function slideShowForward(){
        if(i=7){
            i = 0;
            document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage = images[i];
        }
        else{
            i++;
            document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage = images[i];
        }
}
function slideShowBack(){
        if(i=0){
            i=7;
            document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage = images[i];
        }
        else{
            i--;
            document.getElementById("images").style.backgroundImage = images[i];
        }
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="images">
</div>
<div id="form">
<form name="buttons" action="">
    <input type="button" name="previous" value="Previous" onclick="slideShowBack()"/>
    <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" onclick="slideShowForward()"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: *" my code doesn't work "*. How? What happens and what do you expect to happen? *doesn't work* is not a useful error description.

Comment: Are you giving the *images* element any size through css? Also, please create an example on jsFiddle, this way you can get help easier.

Comment: Did you check image can be loaded?

Comment: @FelixKling Images have all their size in css. I've revised my original post, please see it for my description of issues.

Comment: would you try the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/sunmit9/AZchy/1/) code and check whether it runs on your browser so that we can know whether its only the problem with the background-image property! 

PS. It didnt work in jsFiddle, but worked in my browser after coding.

Comment: @BrianTucker: I've rolled back your edit.  If you're happy with the answer provided by jasssonpet, you should accept it (click the clear check next to it).  Please don't update your questions to contain fixes that resolved the question, that's not really how SO works.

Comment: I just did. I'm still new here and figuring out how to use the site so thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if (i = 0)` to `if (i == 0)`. Same for `if (i = 7)` should be `if ( i == 7)`.

Comment: Do this for all instances of i=something? or only the values in the parentheses. My brain has turned to mush...